# ArduinoPI Python - SERIAL CONNECTION LOST DATA

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

Intent: Control arduino uno from serial port

Tools:

https://github.com/JanStevens/ArduinoPi-Python

I got the server working on both my mac and my Model b+ Raspberry.
The browser behaves as shown in the picture below in both situations.

[image]

To me it looks like the server sent the message to Arduino successfully. But the data somehow gets lost on the way. The Arduino board resets every time I access the url in my browser. I googled and found that a 10uF capacitor between ground and reset pins would prevent the reset from happening. It did, but pin 3 won't go "HIGH". I got a LED+RESISTOR plugged on pin 3 and ground accordingly. I can see the Rx led blinking every time I access the url. So it makes me think that the Arduino is misunderstanding the command from my Flask sever.

OG Arduino code:

```
String cmd;
bool cmdRec = false;
void setup()
{
    //Start the connection with the Raspberry Pi
    Serial1.begin(115200);
    // Start the connection with the Laptop, for debugging only!
    //Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    handleCmd();
}

void serialEvent1() {
    while(Serial1.available() > 0) {
        char inByte = (char)Serial1.read();
        if(inByte == ':') {
            cmdRec = true;
            return;
        } else if(inByte == '@') {
            cmd = "";
            cmdRec = false;
            return;
        } else {
            cmd += inByte;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void handleCmd() {
    if(!cmdRec) return;

    // If you have problems try changing this value, 
    // my MEGA2560 has a lot of space
    int data[80];
    int numArgs = 0;

    int beginIdx = 0;
    int idx = cmd.indexOf(",");

    String arg;
    char charBuffer[20];


    while (idx != -1) {
        arg = cmd.substring(beginIdx, idx);
        arg.toCharArray(charBuffer, 16);

        data[numArgs++] = atoi(charBuffer);
        beginIdx = idx + 1;
        idx = cmd.indexOf(",", beginIdx);
    }
    // And also fetch the last command
    arg = cmd.substring(beginIdx);
    arg.toCharArray(charBuffer, 16);
    data[numArgs++] = atoi(charBuffer);
    // Now execute the command
    execCmd(data);

    cmdRec = false;
}

// For advanced function like switch all the leds in RGB
void execCmd(int* data) {
    switch(data[0]) {
    case 101:
        {
            for(int i = 2; i < (data[1]*2)+1; i+=2) {
                pinMode(data[i], OUTPUT);
                analogWrite(data[i], data[i+1]);
            }
        }
        break;

    case 102:
        {
            pinMode(data[1], INPUT);
            int sensor = analogRead(data[1]);
            Serial1.println(sensor);
        }
        break;

    case 103:
        {
            String result = "";
            int sensor = 0;
            for(int j = 2; j < data[1]+2; j++) {
                pinMode(data[j], INPUT);
                sensor = analogRead(data[j]);
                result += String(sensor)+",";
            }
            Serial1.println(result);
        }
        break;
    default:
        {
            pinMode(data[0], OUTPUT);
            analogWrite(data[0], data[1]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

It does not compile this way. So I uncommented the second Serial.begin line and deleted all the "Serial1." appearances on the code. I can't see no action on the arduino IDE serial when I test it on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

As the code was written with an Arduino Mega that got 2 or 3 serial ports, void serialevent1() is triggered when there is communication going on the the MEGA's SERIAL1 port. Since I am working on the UNO, that only have 1 serial port, all i had to do was delete the "1" before the parenthesis and all worked as supposed.

```
void serialEvent() { }
```